# NPX hardhat commands only return welcome screen

Tags: solidity, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I'm trying to compile and run my code, but currently running any `npx hardhat` command will give me the main screen of

```
Welcome to Hardhat v2.12.2

? What do you want to do? ... 
> Create a JavaScript project
  Create a TypeScript project
  Create an empty hardhat.config.js
  Quit
```

Is there a config file that I need to adjust maybe, or something I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, you need a config file, see the docs https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/config

Comment: I already have one, in Typescript: ```import { HardhatRuntimeEnvironment } from "hardhat/types";
import { DeployFunction } from "hardhat-deploy/types"; 

const deployGovernanceToken: DeployFunction = async function (
    hre: HardhatRuntimeEnvironment
) {}; ```

Comment: That's not how it's supposed to looks like. Make an empty hardhat.config.js, and look at the docs for examples on what to write there

Comment: I have a separate project with a config.js that runs hardhat commands just fine, it seems to just be the one I'm working on with a Typescript deploy script giving me trouble.

Comment: You need 2 config files when deploying with hardhat using TS, `hardhat.config.ts` and `tsconfig.json`. Do you have both of these? Make sure the config file is in `.ts` format.